# Access static field from Java superclass

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class that extends a Java class.

*Kotlin*

```
class MyKotlinClass: MyJavaClass() {

    companion object {
        const val STATUS_SUB = 1
    }
}
```

*Java*

```
public abstract class MyJavaClass {

    public static final int STATUS_SUPER = 0

}
```

How can I access the super class field through the kotlin subclass?

*Kotlin*

```
when(status) {
    MyKotlinClass.STATUS_SUPER -> something()
    MyKotlinClass.STATUS_SUB -> somethingElse()
}
```

Is this possible? It says "unresolved reference: STATUS_SUPER"
Would it be possible without using `MyJavaClass.STATUS_SUPER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
MyJavaClass.STATUS_SUPER
```

Since `STATUS_SUPER` is not a member of `MyKotlinClass` you won't be able to access it.

Comment: is it possible without referring the super class?

Comment: No, because `static` members can't be inherited. Inheritance only works on instances.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. With a Java subclass instead of kotlin, this would be possible

Comment: Yep, that's true.

Comment: Does not seem so. How?